# an image consists of small images which i want to copy separately in html file

Tags: javascript, html, css, html4

```
background: url(images/pg96.png) no-repeat;
```

an image consists of small images which I want to copy separately when opened in browser but don't want to take them separately in html coding?. I am using `html` with `Css` and `JavaScript`.

Comment: where do you want to copy and what is the image????

Comment: can you paste your image here and can u specify which sub-image should be shown?

Comment: If the small images fill the background fully, then you can just set the background-position CSS property to negative values and let only a part of the larger image to be seen. Otherwise, you probably need to play with Canvas.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very much vague but as I understood - You want to use multiple images but you don't want to specify each image in HTML code.

This can be solved by using multiple backgrounds.

```
#example1 {
width: 500px;
height: 250px;
background-image: url(sheep.png), url(betweengrassandsky.png);
background-position: center bottom, left top;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

See if it helps..

Or I'd suggest you to refine your question